# drag & drop image is disabled in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8

Recently I discovered that i can't anymore to drag images from a web page (from IE8) to a local folder. I also have installed xampp and in the localhost I can't select text or right-click (menu doesn't appear). In Opera/FireFox all of this works fine.
Is there any setting that blocks this, can it be fixed?

thanks

Comment: Usually a reboot could fix that problem.

Comment: What happen if you reinstall it? That feature is auto-enabled

Comment: same thing after reboot...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, Protected Mode was on. I just disabled it, restarted IE and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reinstall it since this feature is built-in and auto-enabled in IE8. You can also just try to reboot the computer as Chris mentionned.

Let us know!